# joomla com_users controller overriding

Tags: php, controller, overriding, components, joomla3.4

I can't override the controller of `com_users` (Joomla 3.4). (I want, if a manager can make user registration on the site after when he loged in.So I want to see the registration form, if I loged in the site.)

If I modify the original file, then it works fine,  but I don't want to modify the original file. I tried 2 override plugins for this ([MVC override](https://github.com/phproberto/joomla-mvc-override), Override master). These plugins override the file, but after I click the registration button I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class UsersController in D:\wamp\www\mysite\components\com_users\controller.php on line 136

It's the same file.
I modified the line `class UsersController extends JControllerLegacy` to this `class UsersController extends UsersControllerDefault`. Because I read this [here](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core).
What is the difference? Why doesn't it work this way? :/

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have the MVC override plugin installed be sure to have `"Make Extendable"` set to **yes** in the backend (Plugins: System - MVC Override)
2. I advice you to put all overrides (html, code, etc.) in your template directory, so create the controller file as: `templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/code/com_users/controller.php`
3. Finally, in THIS controller file you override it like it was mentioned:
   `class UsersController extends UsersControllerDefault {`

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. The issue was the that I was also overriding a subcontroller (inside controllers folders)

I had to add

```
$bufferContent = str_replace('extends UsersController','extends UsersControllerDefault',$bufferContent);
$bufferContent = str_replace('require_once', '//require_once', $bufferContent);
```

after

```
$bufferContent = str_replace($originalClass,$replaceClass,$bufferFile);
```

This is a hack and will only work the com_user override. You need to change the first line to reflect your correct component class.